# Python 3 requests, save cookie to disk

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Let's consider the following:

```
import requests
import http.Cookiejar
s = requests.session()
s.get('http://www.wallstreetjournal.com')
```

`s.cookies` returns

```
<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='DJCOOKIE', value='ORC%3Deurope', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.wsj.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False), Cookie(version=0, name='DJSESSION', value='country%3Dde%7C%7Ccontinent%3Deu%7C%7Cregion%3Dhe%7C%7Ccity%3Dfrankfurt%7C%7Clatitude%3D50.12%7C%7Clongitude%3D8.68%7C%7Ctimezone%3Dgmt%2B1%7C%7Czip%3D%7C%7CORCS%3Deurope', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.wsj.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False), Cookie(version=0, name='usr_bkt', value='63L1D4y2F9', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.wsj.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1820320502, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False), Cookie(version=0, name='wsjregion', value='europe', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.wsj.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1507552502, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

I would like to save that cookie to a cookiejar in a simple way, not using pickle or json dump but the cookiejar functionality.

[This page](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1488) seems to suggest that it is as easy as `s.cookies = http.cookiejar.LWPCookieJar(filename="test.cookies")`.

However when i use that line, the cookie in the session becomes empty, and the "test.cookies" is empty file.

EDIT:
I just realise that my example might pose problem, as i replaced my real life problem, which is a site i am subscribe to with that dummy of wall street journal. With the wall street journal example there isn't even a file created, maybe because the cookies of the page are not persistent. But i am not sure how to represent that problem best...

Hopefully this is enough to pinpoint the problem and see why`s.cookies = http.cookiejar.LWPCookieJar(filename="test.cookies")` doesnt work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling `s.cookies = ...` before you make the `s.get()`?

Comment: @AChampion   No I do it in the order stated above

Comment: You need to replace the `cookies` object before you make the `get()` call, so the cookies are saved in that object.

Comment: @AChampion Also i understand the syntax `s.cookies = http.cookiejar.LWPCookieJar(filename="test.cookies")`. This seems to reassign the `s.cookies` value to an empty cookiejar?

Comment: Do it before the `get()` call and the cookies will be saved in the `LWPCookieJar`. Then you can call `s.cookies.save()` after the call.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect for me. Basically, I just adapted the #1488 pull request code the original poster linked so it would work in Python 3. I think AChampion already answered the question but hopefully this will help anyone who might be struggling.

```
import requests
import http.cookiejar

s = requests.Session()
s.cookies = http.cookiejar.LWPCookieJar(filename="cookies.txt")
r = s.get("https://www.google.com")
s.cookies.save()
```